# After updating ios 13, Inapp browser shows error in ionic 3 project

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

After update ios 13. while running inapp browser it shows(Please update your browser) in ios device.

[image]

It shows update browser..But my browser already latest version only..

Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what the the ios-platform version?

Comment: <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />  @sibabratswain

Comment: could you try with 5.0.1
`ionic cordova build ios@5.0.1`

Comment: Updated to 5.0.1. but no changes...its shows as same as above. @sibabratswain